# Mongoose, index locations array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of locations in a document and I want to add a 2dSpere index on that array.  Is that possible?

```
var LocationSchema = new Schema({
  type: { type: String, required: true },
  geometry: {
    type: { type: String, required: true },
    coordinates: { type: Array, required: true}
  },
  properties: Schema.Types.Mixed
});

// Collection to hold users
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    locations: [LocationSchema]
  },{ 
    versionKey: false
  }
);
```

How do I add a 2DSphere index on the geometry field in the locations array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/examples/geospatial/geoJSONSchema.js#L19

LocationSchema.index({ 'geometry' : '2dsphere' });

Comment: I followed the link and Mongo return unknown GeoJSON type: { coordinates: [] }

Answer (score 0):

If you store values for location as 2 numbers in array, then your index would look like:

```
coordinates: { type: [Number], index: '2dsphere', required: true }
```

Although you need to create such index in your database:

```
db.users.ensureIndex({ 'locations.geometry.coordinates': '2dsphere' });
```