# Insert geojson polygons into mongodb and query, based on the coordinates of a point, all the polygons which are located at a certain distance from it

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geospatial, geojson

I need some help on: **how to insert geojson polygons into a mongodb database and query, based on the coordinates of a certain point, all the polygons which are located at a certain distance from that point**

Here is the geojson sample I will use:

```
var testJson =  {
    "type" : "Polygon",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry" : [
        [
            [ 40.8003, -73.9580 ],
            [ 40.7968, -73.9498 ],
            [ 40.7648, -73.9737 ],
            [ 40.7681, -73.9814 ],
            [ 40.8003, -73.9580 ]
        ]
    ]
};
```

I want to save it into the mongodb database and be able to query it.
For this, I do the following:

1. I create a mongoose schema:

   var GeoSchema =  mongoose.Schema({
               "type": { "type": String },
               "properties": { "type": Object },
               "geometry": {
                   "type": Array,
                   "index": '2dsphere'
               }
           });
2. I create a mongoose model:

   var GeoModel = mongoose.model('GeoModel', GeoSchema);
3. I save the geojson to my database:

   var post = new GeoModel(testJson);

   post.save(function(err,doc) {
         if (err) throw err;
         console.log(
           "After Save:\n%s", JSON.stringify( doc, undefined, 4 ) );
   });
4. And, finally I search and find the record:

   GeoModel.find({
           geometry: [
               [ 40.8003, -73.9580 ],
               [ 40.7968, -73.9498 ],
               [ 40.7648, -73.9737 ],
               [ 40.7681, -73.9814 ],
               [ 40.8003, -73.9580 ]
           ]
       }, function(err, records) {
           if (err) return console.log(err);
           console.log(records);
       });

**The issues I need help with:**

I will load lots and lots geojson data in the form of polygons.

Lets say I am located at the following coordinates:
**40.8003, -73.9580**

For a distance of x kilometers, I want to be able all the polygons that are in range.

So, I am thinking of doing a query similar to this, which of course is not working :):

```
GeoModel.find(
    {
        geometry: {
            $near : {
                $geometry : { 
                    type : "Point" , 
                    coordinates : [40.8003, -73.9580]  
                }, 
                $maxDistance : 20000
            }
        },
    }, function(err, records) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(records);
    }
);
```

And I get this error:

```
{ [MongoError: Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=coverageMap.geomodels limit=1000 skip=0
Tree: GEONEAR  field=geometry maxdist=20000 isNearSphere=0
Sort: {}
Proj: {}
 planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=coverageMap.geomodels limit=1000 skip=0\nTree: GEONEAR  field=geometry maxdist=20000 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query',
  '$err': 'Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=coverageMap.geomodels limit=1000 skip=0\nTree: GEONEAR  field=geometry maxdist=20000 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query',
  code: 17007 }
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like my code blocks are not formatting, can an OP help me please?

Comment: Your `geometry` property is not formatted correctly for mongodb to index it. See the answer to this question for the proper syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789364/mongoose-index-locations-array You'll need to empty the collection and update the schema before the index will work.